# how to count number of items in given directory using pure c++ or winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, directory

I mean count non recursively and without regard of the nature of the items (file or dir or whatever) inside. Must I loop the whole dir to count the items or is this number stored somewhere in filesystem and instantly accesible to me ?

Comment: http://cpprocks.com/introduction-to-tr2-filesystem-library-in-vs2012/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looping is techincally necessary. Luckily Visual Studio already has the [`<filesystem>` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694), which means it's a simple matter of calculating `distance(basic_directory_iterator(path), basic_directory_iterator())`

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, using the Windows API, no there is no way to do that without actually enumerating all the files (in the directory). You use the [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) "family" of functions for that.

In the end it [looks like](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090217-00/?p=19123) NTFS (ignoring FAT32 and latest ReFS) doesn't keep track of that information anyway.